# Something fishy is going on in the google-chrome-extension tag

Tags: support, specific-question

I've noticed a pattern of repeated questions by new low-rep users in [google-chrome-extension](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392957/how-to-include-js-in-current-page-html-extension-chrome
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392039/how-to-add-external-js-file-in-current-page-extension
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387603/how-to-show-alert-url-tab-current-page-extension-chrome
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376850/how-to-get-url-in-current-tab-chrome-on-extension-and-done-any-work
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379942/how-to-check-url-current-page-extension-chrome

All of these questions have obvious similarities in writing style, including the greeting "I'm noob in...."  and the salutation  "please guide me about it".

Can these questions be deleted? They have already been asked several times before.

(I would have flagged, but this report didn't fit in a flag, and I'm actually curious about what's happening - I've seen an influx of similar questions in the past week.)

Comment: for the record, I have sent some. .. messages. .

Comment: Why do I imagine [something like this](http://i.imgur.com/qShbZFO.jpg) @AndrewBarber?

Comment: @bart because you have a spycam?

Answer (score 3):

Edit out anything that is irrelevant or offends you, flag to close as a duplicate of one of those that have been asked (hopefully the best instance) - often these are shown automatically in the Related column. Finally, if you think they didn't even try, give them a downvote - they're free.

I'm not sure what "fishy business" can be achieved by asking a lot of basic questions using highly similar wording. If you see the similar wordings coming from different accounts, flag one of the questions and use Other to explain you think this might be a voting ring. But if it's all from the same account, just edit, close, and downvote as appropriate.

Comment: My first instinct is that the asker had being question-banned and was trying to evade it (presumably finding a way around the IP-ban). At least [one user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2515705/janatan) is probably banned: others it might depend on if they have deleted questions.

Comment: The posts, considered individually, are not bad. The volume of those questions are alarming (I've mentioned only 5, but I've seen more than that (I read almost *every* question in the tag). Either someone has lost their credentials, is desperate for an answer or is just trolling. If I don't ring a bell now, odds are that another 5 low quality questions appear the next day.

Comment: Or some lecturer somewhere has set this as an assignment for their large class... @Rob.

Comment: With several of them using the unlikely phrasing "please guide me about it" @benisuǝqbackwards?

Comment: "Please guide me" is Indian English.  The kind of users often associated with fish.